# Download Java using Java

Tags: java, download

I have an application that's built in Java 10. Most users only have Java 8, so they would need to download Java 10 in order to use the application.

Would it be possible to make a launcher that could download Java 10 for them so they wouldn't need to think about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Java 9, there is a new tool named [jlink](https://dzone.com/articles/jlink-in-java-9) that you can use to create a custom Java runtime environment with exactly the parts (modules) that your program needs. You could use this for your program, so that your users don't need to have a pre-installed Java runtime environment at all - you would give them the custom runtime environment included with your game.

Another possibility is to try to compile your program using JDK 8 - you can still [download JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) from Oracle. Depending on how you wrote your program, you might need to change a few things in your code to make it compile and run on Java 8.

Comment: I already have JDK 8 on my computer, but how do I compile it in that? I use the editor IntelliJ IDEA. If you are familiar with this, do you know how to do this with IntelliJ? I'm not that experienced with command line.

Comment: @soni801 You can do that in Project Settings in IntelliJ, see this documentation: [IntelliJ IDEA - Working with projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute your app with JRE (i.e. that's what JetBrains do with their IDE's).

Official Java documentation about this solution:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/deploy/self-contained-application-packaging.htm